# template specilization of a class function

Tags: c++, templates

I tried below specialization for a class function, but it gives me errors.

```
enum SpecializedType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB
};

class TestFunctionSpecialization
{
    public:
        template<SpecializedType T> void print(const T& t)
        {

        }
};

template<> void TestFunctionSpecialization::print<TypeA>(const TypeA& t)
    {

    }
```

The errors are

```
 ../src/TestFunctionSpecialization.h:22:49: error: ‘T’ does not name a type
    template<SpecializedType T> void print(const T& t)
                                                 ^
../src/TestFunctionSpecialization.h:28:65: error: ‘TypeA’ does not name a type
  template<> void TestFunctionSpecialization::print<TypeA>(const TypeA& t)
```

How can I do this specialization properly?

Comment: Well enum values are not types, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do by using them like types.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of template arguments, and you are mixing them:

Type argument, introduced with the keyword `class` or `typename`. For example:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T arg) {}
```

Value argument, introduced with a type, for example:

```
template <int N> int foo() { return N; }
```

Your code declares it as a value argument, but then uses it as a type. That is wrong, and the compiler says so:

```
error: ‘T’ does not name a type
```

We can make your code to compile just removing the arguments:

```
enum SpecializedType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB
};

class TestFunctionSpecialization
{
    public:
        template<SpecializedType T> void print()
        {
            //T is a constant, not a type
        }
};

template<> void TestFunctionSpecialization::print<TypeA>()
{
     //no T declared here!
}
```

But this particular code seems unnecesarily complex, why not just pass `T` as a normal argument to print and avoid the template all together:

```
void print(SpecializedType t)
{
    //use t
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is clearly saying you can't do `const TypeA& t`, as `TypeA` is not a type, but a **value argument**. For instance, think of declaring `const 10& t` (instead of, `const int& t`): what you are trying to do is just as wrong as that.

If all you wanted was to specialize `TestFunctionSpecialization::print`, you are actually close to make it. Forget passing `t` to the method. You won't need it as you are already passing a (template) argument to tell the compiler which method you want to use:

```
template<> void TestFunctionSpecialization::print<TypeA>()
{
  // implementation for the "TypeA" version
}
```

Take a look to a simple example [here](http://ideone.com/VafuZ6).

Answer (score 0):

In `template<SpecializedType T> void print(const T& t)`, `T` is not a template type parameter but a non-type template parameter. You can't use it as a type, it is a value. So you can't write `const &T`.